# Insert result of command into an executable (one command)

Tags: bash, pipe, process-substitution, toolchain

Is it possible to insert the result of a command (or even a chain of commands) into an executable in one command? Something like this:

```
./a.out < echo 0
```

Or is it necessary to do this:

```
echo 0 > input.txt
./a.out < input.txt
```

Comment: You mean a pipe? `echo 0 | ./a.out`

Comment: That works! How to do multiple commands though? `echo 0 | cat test.txt | ./a.out` only inserts `test.txt`.

Comment: Use compound commands `{ echo 0; cat test.txt; } | ./a.out` -> http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html

Comment: @chaos: that is exactly what I was looking for. :-) I've updated your answer and accepted it in advance.

Comment: This should be refered as feeding the output of a command into another as input…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want the program `a.out` to read the output of the command `echo 0` as its input, then you can do that like this:

```
echo 0 | ./a.out
```

Or (this is `bash` specific):

```
./a.out < <(echo 0)
```

---

This `>` and this `<` instead are redirection operators, `>` is the redirection of the output and `<` of the input.

This:

```
echo 0 > input.txt
```

Redirects the output of `echo` to a file called `input.txt`

---

This:

```
./a.out < input.txt
```

Redirects the input of `./a.out`; the source are the contents of `input.txt`.

---

For multiple commands, use [compound commands](http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html):

```
{ echo 0; cat test.txt; } | ./a.out
```

Comment: Thank you! I already tried `./a.out <(echo 0)` but my shell wouldn't accept it! (`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ( `)

Comment: @ultrabowser Sorry, my fault it's `./a.out < <(echo 0)`, it's late...

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that there is a simpler code (in bash):

```
./a.out <<<"0"
```

Or even:

```
 <<<"0" ./a.out
```

If you do not mind the "reverse looking" writing.